# AWS Python Shell - How to use Glue Catalog Connections

Tags: python, apache-spark, jdbc, aws-glue

I have a JDBC connection defined in Glue and I am able to use it successfully in a Glue Spark job. How would I use that same connection in a Glue Python Shell job? I can't find any templates how to do this though I've seen references that it is possible.

An alternative would be how to define a JDBC connection in the Python Shell where I would need to include an external library? `pyodbc` I've read is not available due to dependencies.

Comment: JDBC is for Java, you can't just use it in Python (not without libraries to call Java from Python).

Comment: What data source are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel since I've gone through the work of defining the connection in the Glue Catalog, and that a Glue Spark job (granted spark with spark's associations to Java), that in Python Shell job would also be able to take advantage of the predefined connection. Or are the shell jobs really bare bones and I'm going to have to find a way to store, manage, and create a SQL connection.

Comment: @UjjwalBhardwaj I'm using a MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is code. Make sure same connection is added in your python shell job cloudformation template. We are using pg8000 library.

```
def get_connection(self, conn_name):

        client = boto3.client('glue', region_name=self.region_id)
        response = client.get_connection(Name=conn_name)
        print response

        connection_properties = response['Connection']['ConnectionProperties']
        URL = connection_properties['JDBC_CONNECTION_URL']
        url_list = URL.split("/")

        host = "{}".format(url_list[-2][:-5])
        port = url_list[-2][-4:]
        database = "{}".format(url_list[-1])
        user = "{}".format(connection_properties['USERNAME'])
        pwd = "{}".format(connection_properties['PASSWORD'])

        # print "user:{}".format(user)
        # print "pwd:{}".format(pwd)
        # print "host:{}".format(host)
        # print "port:{}".format(port)
        # print "database:{}".format(database)

        rs_conn = dbapi.connect(database=database, host=host, port=5439, \
                                user=user, password=pwd, ssl=True)
        cur = rs_conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("set statement_timeout = 1200000")
        rs_conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        return rs_conn
```

Comment: Does that mean Python shell cannot use the JDBC connection from Glue, but rather it needs to define a new connection via pg8000 using info extracted from get_connection?

Comment: Yes, because connection setup is done before assigning EC2 for python shell. If it is done without glue connection, then VPC handling should be done via code for newly assigned EC2. I am not sure if that is possible or not.

Answer (score 3):

When you attach a JDBC connection to a Glue Python Shell job, it can only be used by Glue to launch ENIs in the specified subnet with the security groups. The jdbc url, username, password holds no value for the Python Shell job.

Thus, you'll have to provide an external package, like pymssql (http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/), and initialize the connection from the script itself.

You may refer the documentation for Providing Your Own Python Library: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html#create-python-egg-library